# Flutter Firebase DocumentReference.set() is not completing

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My application was writing to Firestore but suddenly stopped working.  When I try to write to Firestore my write method does not complete.  I have made the following simple test method to troubleshoot my problem but can't seem to figure out what is going on:

```
//In database.dart
Future<void> testSet() async {
  final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/test');
  await reference.set({'TEST': 'Value'});
  print('This is never printing');
}

//In home_page.dart called via clicking a button
Future<void> _testSet(context) async {
  final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
  await database.testSet();
}
```

I have tried emptying my Firestore Database as well as adding a `users` collection; however nothing has worked.  Why am I unable to write to Firestore?

Comment: The `Future` returned by the `set` method only completes once the write is committed on the server. Do you have a connection to the server?

Comment: My IOS emulator says it has an internet connection and I have no errors when running flutter doctor.  Also when I start my emulator I get the message: "Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1..."

Comment: I have added a `StreamBuilder` that reads values from the path defined in `testSet()` and have also manually added data to Firestore at the same location. The `StreamBuilder` is reading the manually added data from Firestore and also reads and displays the data from `testSet()` but the database still does not update.  My connection state seems to be active as the snapshot prints as AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.active, ({manually: added}, {TEST: Value}), null, null)

Comment: Hmm... so it's only the set that doesn't happen. Can you check for an exception?

Comment: I tried putting it in a try catch block but there was no exception. I think I figured out the problem; when I go on the Firestore console and enter data manually, then refresh the browser page, the data I entered disappears and does not save. I sent a bug report because that behaviour seemed wrong.

Comment: Could you be out of write quota for the day? I'd still expect that to raise an error, but maybe the Flutter SDK is not raising that up to your code correctly.

Comment: I only reached 12k writes out of the allowed 20k yesterday so I did not exceed my write quota.  When I tried again today everything was working fine. I have no idea why it broke yesterday but this is concerning and is leading me to look into other database options.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?  I'm having the same problem

Comment: @adamcapjones In my case I think I had some recursion error in my code that was making me hit my limits.  The next day, when my limits were reset, I was able to use the database again.